# Stop tagging things with the tag [proofs]

Tags: discussion, tagging

Please!  It is a completely pointless and useless tag.  It applies to somewhere near 80% of the questions that appear on this site.

I will continue to remove this tag whenever it crops up, so please stop adding it.

Answer (score 7):

Agreed.

On that note, have we decided on some standard tags? Might be better to write them somewhere explicitly, since some people (like me) don't frequent Math Overflow.

Comment: I'm really just playing it by ear right now.  I'm removing tags that are really crappy and replacing them with tags that are much  less crappy, but  they are certainly not optimal.

Comment: Standardized tags are a must.  I've been starting to adopt the MathOverflow-style tags (they work really well) if they are already existing here.  But I do believe it is important to standardize our tags before Public Beta comes out.